# Unable to click on orders in Admin Orders

Tags: php, magento, grid, admin, orders

I seem to have fudged something up and I cannot click on the orders in my admin sales>orders grid in Magento 1.5

I cant even click to go the next page...

Here is the overview grid link:

> http://www.thatsmytopper.com/index.php/manage/sales_order/index/key/3686900bdbffc7eead3a4283a269ac33/

When I click on the arrow to go to page 2 I get the same link with a # symbol at the end.

I can view the orders if I click view on the right hand side of each order but the row cannot be clicked on like it used to do.

Any help?

Comment: You've given a link to the backend, so all we see is the login screen. Have you enabled error logging and what is being logged?

Comment: it's pretty clear that you have some js error on your page, try to use FireBug in FF or chrome dev toolbar to determine what causes the js error and eliminate it

Comment: Sorry guys, I didnt mean to give you a link to click on, I was just trying to show what the link structure is and what happens when I click next page. 

I do have firefox, but I cant tell where there might be a js error.  

How can I check the error log, I dont get any errors, it simply doesnt do anything when I hover over the orders.  

I apologize for being a nube.

Comment: Ok. I used firebug and yes the "pointer" function seems lost. I am really lost now on how to fix this or where to begin.

Comment: In a dev environment, step back through any changes made to core files/core JS or any other customizations until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

May not be logged in with the necessary permissions to click through.